# How Can I Animate the Size of A UICollectionViewCell on Scroll so the middle one is largest?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that shows several rows with one, full-width column (looks like a UITableView)

What I'd like to achieve is something similar to this:

[image: UICollectionView with animations]

... where the middle cell has a much greater height. As the user scrolls up and down, the cells before and after the middle cell animate back to the default height for the given cell.

Can somebody outline how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I use this `Swift 3` code in my horizontal `UICollectionView`.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let centerX = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width/2
    for cell in mainCollectionView.visibleCells {

        var offsetX = centerX - cell.center.x
        if offsetX < 0 {
            offsetX *= -1
        }

        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        if offsetX > 50 {

            let offsetPercentage = (offsetX - 50) / view.bounds.width
            var scaleX = 1-offsetPercentage

            if scaleX < 0.8 {
                scaleX = 0.8
            }
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleX)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`.

First of all, override `- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds` to return yes, that way, you can change the layout attributes of your cells as your collection is being scrolled.

After that, your key methods to override are:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

and

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I suggest reading [an article](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html) about custom collection view layouts. It can be pretty heavy subject matter.

Answer (score -1):

since the `UICollectionView` is the subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can solved this problem by treating your collectionView as a scrollView.
set the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implemented `scrollViewDidScroll`, and then do something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
        UIView *cell = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        float position = cell.center.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        float offset = 1.5 - (fabs(scrollView.center.y - position) * 1.0) / scrollView.center.y;
        if (offset<1.0)
        {
            offset=1.0;
        }
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(cell.transform, offset, offset);
    }
}
```

hope this will solve your problem.