# How to set different height and width of cells in horizontal collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have a horizontal collection view and it shows 5 cells at a time and i have adjusted that through **sizeForItemAt** :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
         layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
             sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: (self.numberCollectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/5 - 3, height: (self.numberCollectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/5 - 3 )
    }
```

But these 5 cells would have different width and height and there is a ratio to it. So the **center** item would take 40% of the whole size, the **2nd** and **3rd** item would take 20% of the size and the **1st** and **5th** would take 10% of the size. According to this ratio items size would get change on **scroll**. These items are all **Label**.

**Edit:**
unlike the suggested question and other questions in stackoverflow in my case there is only one row and i have custom **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** to handle the scrolling by cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Animate the Size of A UICollectionViewCell on Scroll so the middle one is largest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324258/how-can-i-animate-the-size-of-a-uicollectionviewcell-on-scroll-so-the-middle-one)

Comment: that question don't even have correct answer

Comment: According to the returned value in `CGSize`, all the cells would be perfect squares and only 5 will be displayed at a time **provided** the inter-item spacing of the cells is 3.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to change the size of the visible center element to 40% of the whole width

Comment: @Fay007 You can set all cell size according to your indexpath Like in this method you can check if indexpath.row == 0 then return this

Comment: @Jecky what will be the indexpath value if i scroll it left as with the change of scroll center cell height has to change dynamically

Comment: it takes as your cell number, nothing effect on cell size with scrolling. Just try it This method calls first then it will go for cellforroaatindexpath

Comment: @Fay007 Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23386007/4539192) answer. It should give a general idea of the approach.

Comment: total shot in the dark and you would need to try it out yourself to see if it works but maybe under delegate method willDisplayCell, get the visible cells and animate the 3rd cell in the index to 40% width of collectionView and animate the 2nd cell in index back to 20%. You would also need to keep track of the indexPath of displayed cell to know which way you are scrolling which will effect what cell you animate to which size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UICollectionViewFlowLayout to handle the scrolling by cell:**

```
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x
        let targetRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0, width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.height)

        for layoutAttributes in super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)! {
            let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
            if (abs(itemOffset - horizontalOffset) < abs(offsetAdjustment)) {
                offsetAdjustment = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
            }
        }

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

}
```

**Then to find the center cell of the `CollectionView`:**

```
private func findCenterIndex() -> Int {
        let center = self.view.convert(numberCollectionView.center, to: self.numberCollectionView)
        let row = numberCollectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: center)?.row


        guard let index = row else {

            return 0
        }

        self.rating = index

        return index

    }
```

**under `scrollViewDidScroll`transformed cell:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


            transformCell()

    }



    private func transformCell() {


        let row =  findCenterIndex()

        var offset : Float = 0.0

        for cell in numberCollectionView.visibleCells as! [VotingCell] {

            if row == numberCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row {

                offset = 1.1
                cell.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28.0)
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.black
                cell.alpha = 1.0
                cell.label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            else if row == (numberCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row)! + 1 || row == (numberCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row)! - 1
            {
                offset = 0.8
                cell.label.font = UIFont(name: cell.label.font.fontName, size: 26.0)
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.gray
                cell.alpha = 0.8
                cell.label.textAlignment = .center

            }
            else if row == (numberCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row)! + 2 || row == (numberCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row)! - 2 {

                offset = 0.7
                cell.label.font = UIFont(name: cell.label.font.fontName, size: 20.0)
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.gray
                cell.alpha = 0.8
                cell.label.textAlignment = .center
            }
            else
            {
                offset = 0.00

            }


            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(offset), y: CGFloat(offset))

        }
    }
```

also called `transformCell()` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for initial load.

Comment: I could not understand 2 points in your code. What came from  [VotingCell] and  self.rating  ?